# Link dynamic library and ffmpeg x86_64 version

Tags: ffmpeg, g++, dylib

I'm working with FFMPEG on Mac OSX, my Mac version is 10.6.8 (i386).

When I try to compile my C++ code linking a dynamic library:

```
g++ sdk.cpp -rpath /usr/local/lib/libinsight.dylib -o sdk
```

I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
    start in crt1.10.6.o
  "av_open_input_file(AVFormatContext**, char const*, AVInputFormat*, int,  AVFormatParameters*)", referenced from:
    ffmpeg_open(AVFormatContext**, char const*, int*)in ccCkx9dd.o

  (so forth fo every FFMPEG call)

  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Without linking dylib I have no problem. What's the matter?

P.S. ffmpeg version is Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Answer (score 0):

> `g++ sdk.cpp -rpath /usr/local/lib/libinsight.dylib -o sdk`

Shouldn't you be linking to `libffmpeg` somewhere? Try adding `-lffmpeg` to your link command line.